# How to Insert time in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

I'm doing a project to catering item hiring service. They want to save the date and time customer hire their items also save the date and time customer return them. Of course any of those not gona be actual at the movement date or time.   So first of all I'm trying to find to save any date and time. Other activities will concern later. So I came up with little table. like  given below.

```
 ID   |  Name     |  Value   |    Date    |    Time
(int) | (Varchar) |( Double) | (DateTime) | (DateTime)
```

And I used this cord to save data.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
     String date=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dat.getDate()); 
     String time = String.valueOf(dateSpinner.getValue()).split(" ")[3];

     try {                                                                                                                                                
         new JDBC().putData("INSERT INTO work (name, balance, date) VALUES ('"+txtName.getText()+"',"+txtValue.getText()+"', '"+date+"', '"+time+"') ");
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "value saved");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() +" "+e);
     } 
}
```

When I'm entering data I'm having

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3" .
```

Help me to find the error of this cord and save any time. Actually I can save any date using String Date variable. I saved some demo data before I added time field to table. But I'm having this problem when I'm trying to save time. I am using date Spinner to save time. But I can't format it as `HH-mm--ss`. If you know another time saving feature please let me know. Please help me.

Comment: What is `String.valueOf(dateSpinner.getValue()).split(" ").length`?  Or better yet, what is `String.valueOf(dateSpinner.getValue())`?

Comment: you have an error in the SQL statement as well. you defined only three columns, but you are trying to add four values.

Comment: you have the error in this line: `String time = String.valueOf(dateSpinner.getValue()).split(" ")[3];`

the index [3] not exisits.

Comment: @lucian I corrected it as new JDBC().putData("INSERT INTO work (name, balance, date) VALUES ('"+txtName.getText()+"','"+txtValue.getText()+"', '"+date+"') "); so I can save date I choose as before. But guys if I'm not using String time = String.valueOf(dateSpinner.getValue()).split(" ")[3]; what I'm gona use to save time I want. Please explain to me. Give a good option to save any time.

Comment: @lucian I removed [3] too. Still have save error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
String time = String.valueOf(dateSpinner.getValue()).split(" ")[3];
```

Is the same as this, just done on a single line

```
String[] splitArr = String.valueOf(dateSpinner.getValue()).split(" ");
String time = splitArr[3];
```

The error you are getting is saying that there is not 4 elements in the split array. Put in the below piece of code to debug what you are getting so you know what is happening in that single line

```
String[] splitArr = String.valueOf(dateSpinner.getValue()).split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < splitArr.length; i++)
{
     System.out.println("Element number " + i + " is \"" + splitArr[i] + "\"");
}
```

Then you can update your insert appropriately. Sorry I cant be of more help but we do not know what `datespinner` is or what `datespinner.getValue()` returns so do the above to help debug your code.